# 'operator new': redefinition, different linkage (using _dllspec on redefined new operator)

Tags: c++, dll, linker, extern

I am using __declspec(dllimport/export) on a debug version of new as such:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
 DECLSPECCORE extern   void* operator new(unsigned int size, const char* file, int line);
 extern void* operator new[](unsigned int size, const char* file, int line);
 extern void operator delete(void* address, const char* file, int line);
 extern void operator delete[](void* address, const char* file, int line);
 extern void Delete(void* address);

#define LUDO_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define LUDO_DELETE delete

#endif
```

This is causing me to get

> error C2375: 'operator new':
>   redefinition; different linkage.

Why is this and how can you fix it? This is the only project that I am compiling right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two two prototypes of overloading the new operator you must export both. Hopefulyl that is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ runtime itself provides an `operator new`, which is not marked as `DECLSPECCORE` -- hence "different linkage", the original was not imported from another module.  If you intend to override `operator new`, it should have the same linkage as before.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to move the new and delete operator to it's own namespace.
all types in that namespace should than use the new and delete operator of that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying that you want C++'s "operator new" to be exported as a function callable from outside the DLL.  Assuming that's even possible (probably not):  Are you sure that's what you want to do?